# Cannot connect to Openshift using Intellij [OpenshiftException]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, deployment, openshift

I use the Github login credentials to enter to the Openshift Web Console (Next Gen) but I cannot using Intellij for deploy my application as the only way to login is using a token and the `oc` commands in the prompt. Is there a way to use my token to deploy using IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the Idea integration, but if I understand correctly you can provide a token. So why can you not do something like

```
oc login --token=<your-token> --server=https://api.preview.openshift.com/oapi/v1/users/~
```

So token you can retrieve from the developer preview website under the help menu.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of, there is no integration available between IntelliJ and OpenShift. The easiest form of deployment is a [Github webhook](https://docs.openshift.com/online/getting_started/beyond_the_basics.html#btb-configuring-automated-builds) which will automatically deploy upon commit. However, you can also easily deploy a local application by using `oc new-app /path/to/app/directory`, and you can even set up a service to [push local webhooks](https://blog.openshift.com/using-github-hooks-with-your-local-openshift-environment/) to OpenShift

Answer (score 0):

With IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 there will be an option for this, via "Build, Execution, Deployment > OpenShift":

[image: OpenShift with token]

Related Bugticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176760